# Converting date HH:MM to numeric values

Tags: php, jquery, date

So I have a couple of HTML fields containing working hours. For example, a user could enter `08:15` (which should give me `8.25`) and `12:30` (which should give me `12.5`).

How would this be done? I was thinking of having a start date of 1 Jan 1970, adding the hours to it, converting it to a timestamp and then do the other math but I'm not sure if this is the right way and I even might overlooked some (obvious) function.

Comment: How about `mins + (secs / 60)`?

Comment: change HH:MM to numeric values for what purpose?

Comment: there is `jquery` and `php` tag, but in question I don't see in which language you want to parse

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$string = "08:15";

$items = explode(":",$string);
$hours = intval($items[0]);
$minutes = intval($items[1]);

$decimalhours = $hours + ($minutes / 60);
echo $decimalhours;
```

This code is by no means robust as it fails when the user does not adhere to the strict syntax you're requiring. Nevertheless it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense. The resulting value has to be cast to float (implicitly done here) in order to be working as requested.

Comment: +1 for `intval()` although your explode could be made a bit clearer with a `list($hours, $minutes) = `

Comment: @PhpMyCoder clearer with intval()? May I see the code if you don't mind?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think you misunderstood. I meant that instead of using `$items = explode(':', $string);` and then referring to hours with `$items[0]` and minutes with `$items[1]`, the meaning would be clearer with `list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $string);`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder you just made this code more complex, if you didn't notice

Comment: @YourCommonSense Complexity is subjective. But I think we can both agree that `$minutes` has more meaning than `$items[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so tricky, so you may do it this way:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', '12:30');

$hours += $minutes / 60;

echo $hours;
?>
```

And write your own function:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function time2dec($time, $delimiter = ':'){
    list($h, $m, $s) = array_pad(explode($delimiter, $time), 3, 0);
    return $h + $m / 60 + $s / 3600;
}

echo time2dec('12:30'), PHP_EOL;
echo time2dec('12:15'), PHP_EOL;
echo time2dec('12:15:15'), PHP_EOL;
echo time2dec('12:a:15'), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Shows:

```
12.5
12.25
12.254166666667
12.004166666667
```

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the idea how it can be calculated (Expect you to code :D)

1. Let MM part be `x`
2. Now your result will be `y= 5/3 * x`

   So as an example, if it is 8:15, then
   x = 15
   y = 5/3*15 = 25
   so the result is 8.25